# MYSQL 5.7 / PHPmyadmin 4.5.4.1 Incorrect selected record statement counts for complex queries using group by and derived tables

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm using MySQL 5.7 in strict mode (default install settings). The following query returns the reduced results I'm seeking, but after turning it into a derived table to connect other tables too, I see that the grouping seems to be undone, PHPmyadmin is saying the row count is back to the original, yet the counts are still the same in the count column showing how many records per group.... is this a phpmyadmin error or am I just going crazy?

Total records in Table 5150.

This query returns 5104 results:

```
SELECT `Id`, MAX(`code-order`) AS `max-code-order`
FROM `codes`
GROUP BY `Id`
```

The following returns 5150 results:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT `Id`, MAX(`code-order`) AS `max-code-order`
     FROM `codes`
     GROUP BY `Id`) AS `max-codes`
```

**Update 1**:

I Just made a table to insert the data into... phpmyadmin reports 5104 records inserted, take away the insert statement and run the raw query, 5150. Known bug, or am I just missing something here?

**Update 2**:

I just tried the second query (the one with the derived table), and instead of selecting all columns, I used COUNT(*) and the number I got... 5104, take out the count, 5150 records reportedly selected. Mysql or phpmyadmin error. Not sure which one it is.

**Update 3**:

Just opened a bug report: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12533

Reposted here for convenience:

**Steps to reproduce**:

1. Create an INNODB table with duplicate values that can be grouped by. Run MYSQL 5.7 in DEFAULT SQL MODE (strict).
2. Run Query like this, where `Id` is the duplicate value column:

   ```
   SELECT `Id`, FROM `table` GROUP BY `Id`
   ```

Note the number of reported selected rows at top (in the green box).

3. Run same query as derived table like this:

   ```
   SELECT 'Id' FROM (SELECT `Id`, FROM `table` GROUP BY `Id`) as `test`
   ```

Note the number of reported selected rows at top  (in the green box) is now the full number of rows in that table.

4. Run query again, but using COUNT(*)

   ```
   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT `Id`, FROM `table` GROUP BY `Id`) as `test`
   ```

Same number of rows reported in the actual returned table COUNT(*) column as was returned in step 2 query.

NOTE: Try running queries in steps 2 and 3 with a COUNT column added in. You will see that the counted values are the same.

**Expected behavior**: selected records statement should report original subquery selected result number.

**Actual behavior**: selected records statement reports full number of rows PRE group by instead.

**Server configuration**:

- Operating system: Ubuntu 16.04
- Web server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
- Database: MySQL 5.7.13 - default sql_mode set (strict)
- PHP version: 7.0
- phpMyAdmin version: 4.5.4.1deb2ubuntu2

**Client configuration**:

- Browser: Firefox 48
- Operating system: Kubuntu 16.04

Comment: i recommend you test your SQL statements from another client, like the mysql command line client. And compare to the behavior you are observing from phpmyadmin. I'm not familiar with phpmyadmin, and It's not clear to me where the "5150 records reportedly selected" is coming from. There's not enough information in the question to reproduce the scenario.

Comment: @spencer7593 - I just posted my bug report with steps to reproduce. Thanks. I'm getting the sense that this is a phpmyadmin issue, since the COUNT(*) comes back correctly, and the inserts are correct, yet the phpmyadmin result note is off.